# grails database migration plugin - how to conditionally insert rows

Tags: grails, database-migration, liquibase

How would I write a changelog.groovy for the grails database migration plugin that would insert rows into a table if a row doesn't already exist for a range of ids?  For example.

cool_stuff table has
id | some_other_id |

The cool_stuff table is populated with data.  Given a range of cool_stuff ids, 1 - 2000, I would like to:

1. Iterate through the ids, querying the cool_stuff table to see if the combination of cool_stuff id and some_other_id = 2 exists
2. If it doesn't exist, insert a row with the cool_stuff id and some_other_id = 2

Comment: Could this be done in changelog.xml instead of changelog.groovy?

Answer (score 0):

1. Threre are recoreds on "cool_stuff" table already.
2. You need conbination of a record that "cool_stuff.id" and "some_other_id == 2"

so, do you want like following?

```
table of "cool_stuff"

FROM:
id  | some_other_id
----|---------------
1   | 2
2   | 1
3   | 2
4   | 1

TO:
id  | some_other_id
----|---------------
1   | 2
2   | 1
3   | 2
4   | 1
2   | 2
4   | 2
```

Is this right??
I would like to do like following if i do that.

```
databaseChangeLog = {
    changeSet(author: "koji", id: "123456789") {
        grailsChange {
            change {
                CoolStuff.list().findAll {
                    it.someOtherId != 2
                }.each{
                    // save new instance
                    new CoolStuf(id: it.id, someOtherId:2).save(flush:true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```